# How can I show result in foreach and regexp in sequence of variables

Tags: list, variables, foreach, tcl

I am having difficulty writing this small code, from which the three variables present are to be output. But when running with tcl, only the first variable is displayed in duplicate: *Diego Diego Diego* ; and not in sequence as I would like it to be: *Diego Henrique Guilherme*.

**My sample code:**

```
set name0 "\[Diego\]"
set name1 "\[Henrique\]"
set name2 "\[Guilherme\]"

set lst {}

lappend lst [list $name0 $name1 $name2]

set num {0 1 2}

foreach a $lst b $num {

    set x [lindex $a $b]

    regexp "\[\[(.*?)\](.*?)\]" $x value out

    puts $out
}
```

I wasn't able to identify the error. If anyone can point out to me the flaw I'll be grateful.

> I want to get this output: ***Diego Henrique Guilherme***

Comment: Why is that regular expression written like that?   I don't understand why you have two pairs of square brackets and two capturing parentheses.

I would've just done this:  `{\[(.*)\]}`   which is a capture group inside of literal square brackets.  I use the backslash to avoid the square brackets being considered like a regexp bracket expression holding a character class.

Comment: @Chris Heithoff In my actual file/code, I have two entries between the brackets, like this: `"\[Name Diego\]"`, so when I drew up the example for the question it was as it is in the sample code `"\[\[(.*?)\](.*?)\]"`. But Thank you for your observation, just do not think it pays to edit the question to correct the example since I got the answer i expected.

Comment: okay, that explains the two capturing groups.   

I still don't understand why so many square brackets though.  

It's difficult to express Tcl regular expressions inside double quotes because you need to backslash escape so many things.  It's usually better to write them inside curly braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, lst become a list of one element where the first element is a list of three items.
Instead of

```
set lst {}
lappend lst [list $name0 $name1 $name2]
```

just do

```
set lst [list $name0 $name1 $name2]
```

Comment: Once you have that, you also don't need the `lindex`

Comment: Doh, I was wrong, thanks to Glenn for the correction.

Comment: I thank all that contributed to the question, be through comments and response, as well as in the edition of the question. I'm thankful to!